# Implement Task Recurrence Pattern in .NET like Outlook?

Tags: asp.net, outlook, scheduling

I have to implement Scheduler like outlook in my .NET application.I have already started working on it but I can't implement Recurrence Pattern.please suggest me that how could i achieve this functionality.
how to save task with Recurrence in database?
I found this [RadScheduler for ASP.NET AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/outlook2007/defaultcs.aspx) but unfortunately this controller is commercial

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html)

This is an open source library that does exactly what you want, sans any UI component.