# Optimal C# Implementation for Interfacing with Outlook's Recurrence Pattern and Calendar

Tags: c#, architecture, calendar, outlook

Should I reference the [Outlook Interop Recurrence Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern_members.aspx) object from my core object code or should I duplicate its "interface" (and I use that term loosely) within my core and then communicate with Outlook in another layer?

I'm a small developer in a small company with a small software product. For years, customers have clamored for Outlook interoperability in our C#/SQLServer RDBMS. We're finally making it happen for them, but an Outlook Add-in is out of scope.

Thanks to stackoverflow and google (and of course the MS documentation), I've got our program successfully saving appointments, cancelling meetings, sending invites... Now we need to decide how to handle recurrences.

I was looking at Outlook's "Appointment Recurrence" window (and comparing it with Google Calendar's "Repeat" window) when I started to feel myself getting sucked in... As I hinted above, we usually avoid "Yak Shaving," but we'll re-invent the wheel if that's what it takes to keep control of our products.

I understand that other people have already [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3660945/232271) this problem, but our management will probably never let us go that route.

Comment: Do you only need to create recurring items, and not process already existing ones?

Comment: We're currently maintaining only the calendar items created by our program  (i.e., the items whose EntryID we know). I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in order to implement Outlook's functionality, you would need `DayOfMonth`, `DayOfWeekMask`, `Duration`, `EndTime`, `Instance`, `Interval`, `MonthOfYear`, `PatternStartDate`, `RecurrenceType`, `StartTime`, and some way to specify when it ends.

Although Outlook uses some combination of `Occurrences`, `NoEndDate`, and `PatternEndDate` to specify the end, you could use a nullable `PatternEndDate` or a nullable `Occurrences` to satisfy the functionality.

I believe the actual Outlook object has specific validation rules built in that may require properties to be set in a specific order. I would implement my own object that only performs validation at the right time and then sets the Outlook object's properties in the proper order.